# Finding coordinates of gesture touch using locationOfTouch

Tags: iphone, ios, coordinates, uigesturerecognizer, cgpoint

Hey, been trying to get the location of a users swipe so that I can have 3 swipe-able areas on screen and determine which section they react with based on the y coordinates of their swipe.

This is the code

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:nil];
```

I have tried printing the touchPoint.y in a label and all i get is 0. How do I get the coordinates of the users swipe?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling this method?

Comment: @Deepak Inside this function.. `- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer { CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:nil]; if (touchPoint.y >= 160){ if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) { } else { } `

Comment: @Anna Karenina `int tou = touchPoint.y;
   NSString *to = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", tou];
   touch.text = to;`

Comment: Instead of `inView:nil` try `inView:recognizer.view`.

Comment: That worked, thanks @Karenina if you want to post it as an answer then I can confirm it as an answer for everyone :)

Comment: @Wezly, Deepak's answer is basically the same.  self.view will work if that's the view you're adding the recognizer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its strange but setting view as `nil` or `self.view.window` is returning 0. There is no mention of such behavior and [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on UISwipeGestureRecognizer seems to encourage finding the origin of the swipe using this method. It would be a good idea to file this under a bug.

This is working for other views though. Say `self.view`.