# ios - UIPanGestureRecognizer how to get the touched coordinate relative to [gestureRecognizer view]

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

In my code I need to find the coordinate a user touched and is currently panning.
I've set up the following code based on - [Touch Coordinates from UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196558/touch-coordinates-from-uipangesturerecognizer)

It looks as following:

```
    CGPoint pos = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:[gestureRecognizer view]];
```

However the values returned by this method are either negative, or larger than the view's own frame.  How can that be? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at this one it might be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060438/finding-coordinates-of-gesture-touch-using-locationoftouch

Comment: still no luck, negative or very high values

Comment: In short, you're probably doing nothing wrong. If you start a continuous gesture inside the view for which the gesture has been defined, but continue it outside of that view, the gesture will continue (which is very good thing), appropriately showing you negative or large numbers. If you want the action inside the gesture to be constrained by the view, you do that within your gesture handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one its giving me the coordinates of x and y

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureUp locationOfTouch:0 inView:gestureUp.view];
    if (touchPoint.y <= 160)
    {
        if (gestureUp.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)
        {
            NSLog(@"the location x...%f",touchPoint.x);
            NSLog(@"the location y...%f",touchPoint.y);
        }
        else
        { }
    }
    return YES;
}
```